# Angular 6 error TS2339: Property 'scrollUp' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-template

I am using jQuery in Angular 6. I have installed following steps:

```
npm install jquery
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

and I have added jQuery in my angular.json like this:

```
"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
"src/assets/js/plugins.js"
```

plugins.js has custom functions of jQuery. In my header.component.ts file when I use one of these functions from plugins.js it gives following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/includes/header/header.component.ts(31,9): error TS2339: Property 'scrollUp' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'.
```

header.component.ts file looks like this:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";

declare const meanmenu: any;
declare const scrollUp: any;
 ngOnInit() {
  $.scrollUp({
        scrollText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>',
        easingType: 'linear',
        scrollSpeed: 900,
        animation: 'slide'
      });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
interface jQueryStatic {
  scrollUp: any;
}
```

and

```
($ as any).scrollUp({
        scrollText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>',
        easingType: 'linear',
        scrollSpeed: 900,
        animation: 'slide'
      });
```

worked for me ...